# How to read environment variable during build time when using baseimage-docker from phusion

Tags: docker, phusion

I build my docker image using based on [phusion/baseimage](https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker)

The command I run to build my image is:

```
docker build --build-arg ENV_FILE=.env -t demo:latest .
```

my .env file looks like this:

```
VAR1=foo
VAR2=bar
```

and my dockerfile is like this

```
FROM phusion/baseimage:jammy-1.0.1

ARG VAR1

# I would like to print VAR1
RUN echo "my var1 equals to : $VAR1"
```

However I can't get VAR1 printed, it just shows an empty value

```
....
 ---> Running in 8f78bb5d59cc
my var1 equals to :
```

Any idea how I can read it when building the image?

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
(source .env; docker build --build-arg VAR1=$VAR1 -t demo:latest .)
```

You have to specify each variable though. I don't think there's a way to pass them all in as build arguments. .env files are meant for use at run-time.